# Return null in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want use this code but it returns NULL in all this parameters ! would you please help how to fix it or what is the problem ?

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bHcS.png) for a picture that shown what happened.

code :

```
    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Crawler("http://www.avval.ir/directory", 0);
        }

    public void Crawler(string url, int pid)
        {


            try
            {

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://www.avval.ir/directory");
                HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='metatag-topi metatag-keywords']");
                HtmlNodeCollection nodes2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='pagination']/a[@href]");
                HtmlNodeCollection phone = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='phone fRight ml10']");

            }
        }
```

Comment: @KrzysiekBronek Thank you for your help but it still doesn't work. If its possible help me more on this project and if you think you need whole project I can post all of them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, it seems you have a typo in your xpath selector, see:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = 
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='metatag-topi metatag-keywords']");
```

Here you use `//a[@class='metatag-topi metatag-keywords']` expression that selects all the `<a>` tags with `class` attribute value `metatag-topi metatag-keywords`. But the thing is, the page you're trying to apply your expression doesn't contain such elements, but has some `<a class="metatag-topic metatag-keywords">` (missing `c` letter in the end of the word `topic`).

Just change that line to:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = 
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='metatag-topic metatag-keywords']");
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `DocumentNode.SelectNodes` could return null if no nodes are not found.

You may check this related [Why DocumentNode.SelectNodes returns null](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29175)

Comment: @KrzysiekBronek Thank you for your help but it still doesn't work. If its possible help me more on this project and if you think you need whole project I can post all of them here.